# Stock image dump for running Magisk necessary?

Tags: rooting, root-access, magisk, android-one, mi-a2

In the offitical [installation instructions for Magisk](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445) it says: “However, you MUST have a stock boot image dump beforehand, and you also have to be able to flash the patched boot image, either through fastboot/download mode or ODIN”

*What’s the rationale for having the stock boot image dump beforehand?*

If the rationale is to have a backup when something goes wrong, then strictly having a stock boot image dump is not necessary for running Magisk.

Furthermore, it is unclear to me how to create that dump.

PS: My plan is to root the Xiaomi A2, to be able to directly interface with USB OTG devices from within [Termux](https://termux.com/). The Xiaomi A2 is an Android One device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Stock image dump for running Magisk necessary?

**No**. Far more easier is to use the [flashable ZIP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=77284282&postcount=3792) that does all- That performs all the steps: backing up the boot image, creating a patched version, flashing that, installing Magisk Manager (thanks to Izzy in comments)

But to clarify on the instructions

> What’s the rationale for having the stock boot image dump beforehand?

For devices that **don't have custom recovery** but you would want to root

Magisk needs the stock boot image for two things

- To be able to *patch* it so that Magisk can be installed.
- If you wish to uninstall Magisk, it replaces the patched boot image with stock boot image

> Furthermore, it is unclear to me how to create that dump

For MiA1 you can see the details on this [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-a1/how-to/guide-rooting-mi-a1-twrp-wiping-post-t3824550). In essence:

- You need to have fastboot image of the stock ROM (for MiA1 they are released [every month](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-a1/how-to/ota-xiaomi-mi-a1-ota-links-t3718542))
- Extract boot.img and store it on your device
- Install [Magisk Manager](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases) .Tap on Install on the prompt and then "Patch Boot Image File". Select the untouched boot.img through your File Explorer. Wait for it to do its thing.
  The patched_boot.img was created and it should be located at `/storage/emulated/0/MagiskManager/patched_boot.img`.
- Copy the patched boot.img to your PC and fastboot into it (`fastboot boot patched_boot.img`)
- From Magisk manager *Direct Install* and you are done

If that is too much work, you can wait for somebody at XDA to provide patched boot images

Edit : See this for more [How do you root a device with Magisk when it doesn't have a custom recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232257/131553)