# Cheap phone disabled flashing with mispelled error message

Tags: rooting, root-access, recovery-mode, fastboot, 8.0-oreo

I have an 'Advanced A4 2019' phone from BLU, and it's known to have spyware. I wanted to flash the phone's recovery with TWRP to install a custom ROM, but I can't seem to enable flashing. It runs android 8.1 at the moment.

Commands I've tried in fastboot:

**fastboot getvar all**

```
all: 
Finished. Total time: 0.000s
```

**fastboot oem device-info**

```
FAILED (remote: 'unknown cmd.')
```

**fastboot flashing lock**

```
FAILED (remote: 'Not implement.')
```

.

(This is the good one)

**fastboot flashing unlock**

```
FAILED (remote: 'Not implemet.')
```

That's not my typo, it says not implemet. Also, its worth mentioning that the screen that pops up in fastboot is different from the normal one. Has the binary just been patched and there's no way to put my own OS on it? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220768

Comment: @alecxs I can't flash, that's the issue
And I can't su until I flash and root

Comment: no MTK_AllInOne_DA.bin, auth_sv5.auth?

Comment: @alecxs Just downloaded SP, I'm going to try it out and I'll update

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220584

Comment: @alecxs I can't use SP, I can't find the scatter file
Edit: I'm on a linux computer so I can't get the MTK tools

Comment: is this your phone model and ROM version? https://androidhost.ru/Ueo

Comment: MTK droid tools is outdated, create scatter file with [WwR MTK](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=813767)

Comment: @alecxs Good find! Yeah, that's the ROM, I just cant seem to replace it. Although if I recall, there's a mode that you can get to from recovery that'll let you do it

Comment: @alecxs That link is dead and everything else is super shady. Is there a way to get it with adb?

Comment: try mtk-su but i strongly recommend creating your own scatter and make a full ROM dump with WwR MTK and SP Flash Tool before mess up

Comment: links working fine you probably didn't login 4pda.ru it's the official documentation from the original author vvaaavv