# How to tell if phone mirrored or hacked

Tags: stock-android

I keep having apps on phone I didn't install yet cannot disable. Phone screen keeps doing its own thing. Google maps timeline keeps being edited. Lots of unusual stuff like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Malware automatically installing unless I disable the play store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220768/malware-automatically-installing-unless-i-disable-the-play-store)

Comment: https://www.symantec.com/blogs/threat-intelligence/xhelper-android-malware

Answer (score 1):

It usually can happen because of fall of the phone from height. Maybe your display touch is broken, so it's touching the apps or texting somethings by itself. Try to hard reset your phone. I am not sure but it can help you. Otherwise, you should give your phone to hardware repairer.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, happened to me before too. One way to check: can you, the human, still use your phone normally? swipe, tap, etc., on different parts of the screen, and have the expected results? If all that is normal, probably it is not a broken touch screen. If it is not normal, then probably it is a broken touch screen.