# My problem is that it crashes and after I do a hard reset in the Chinese Wipe MMC menu, instead of the standard 32 applications, I get 57?

Tags: adb, 7.0-nougat, zte

I have a smartphone brand **Motorola C Plus, Android 7.0.**,

My problem is that it crashes and after I do a hard reset in the Chinese Wipe MMC menu, instead of the standard 32 applications, I get 57 ?*!

After testing in the English menu I saw that there are log files that the system does not remove? Does the problem come from a launcher update or another program, or is there hacker intervention? After turning off the internet card, Bluetooth and wifi, the ordinary hacker could hardly enter? How to do system cleaning manually with USB cable commands from a personal computer when connected to it?

I activated ADB commands, but I could not see where I install the new 25 applications for music, video and others to destroy their installation archives.

Comment: "*instead of the standard 32 applications*" I'm a bit curious about this statement, where did you get this info from? Also, what are those 25 additional apps?

Comment: Evernote; Mój T-Mobile; Tidal;....

Comment: Some ROMs contain apps they install dependent of location and other criteria on first reboot after factory reset. Those apps are then pre-installed but those apps are not really system apps and you should be able to totally uninstall them.

Comment: After resetting to factory settings, I think the ROM needs to load up to 32 applications, most of which can be uninstalled or disabled. This is clear, but the problem is that I have 32 others installed - audio, video, navigation ... in some of these others probably lies the reason why my device turns off, restarts itself or blocks. I need to remove the battery and wait for hours to turn it back on in a few seconds or minutes .... Antivirus does not detect a virus, so either new applications overflow my memory, or there is a log file that restarts, or the logger is damaged ??!

Comment: or simply device is end of life because of eMMC wear-out? you can however disable packages from adb (no root required) or uninstall from temporary root shell (mtk-su) or flash stock ROM from fastboot/SP Flash Tool (beware of golden rules)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Malware automatically installing unless I disable the play store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220768/malware-automatically-installing-unless-i-disable-the-play-store)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redmi note 9 brick](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232584/redmi-note-9-brick)

Comment: I activated the option for programmers and it got even worse ... now even without a card my phone crashes, even during a test in root integrity check ?? Clearing the cache and user settings do not help, obviously something else needs to be deleted in memory ?? Where are the files I see from in root integrity check deleted?